# Lync Skype Meeting - Generate the Meeting URL

Tags: oauth, office365, lync, skype-for-business

Currently, the application is able to create and Outlook Meeting Event using Office 365 REST API. Therefore, it goes through the authentication, get the Access_Token, then create the new event.

With Microsoft Outlook, when I click on the button Skype Meeting, it generates a  Join Skype Meeting URL stamped in the body for the meeting (example is below), and I like to include that URL for "Join Skype Meeting" in that application for create new event.

```
Join Skype Meeting      
https://meet.lync.com/OrganizationName/FirstName.LastName/L03XXXXX
```

The IT person has already grant permission Skype for Business to the application on Azure Active Directory.

Can I use the same Access_Token for event to generate a Join Skype Meeting URL for Lync API?  Any advices on how to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

First thing you need to realise is that there are two different systems involved.

- Skype For Business User Conference
- Office / Office 365 Calendar Entry

The 'Skype For Business User Conference' is what the meeting URL points to and what 'Skype' clients know about.  They know nothing about the Office Calendar Entry.

The Office 'Skype Meeting' Calendar Entry has 'extra' metadata pointing to the 'Skype For Business User Conference' (including the URI).

So you don't need to create a Office Calendar Entry to create or use a 'Skype For Business User Conference'.  To create a Skype meeting you can use the UCWI API [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/scheduleanonlinemeeting) (or if you are doing everything within a web browser you can use the WebSDK, which is a wrapper around the UCWA API [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/schedulemeeting)).  Once you have created a Skype user conference you will have the meeting URI to point people to.

If you *need* to create a 'Skype' meeting Calendar entry, then we run into the problem in that the metadata for these calendar entries is not documented by Microsoft anywhere (that I have found).

The best approach is the generate a 'Skype' meeting manually then dump the added metadata.  Then figure out what you need to change in the metadata and then 'add' the metadata to your API created calendar entry yourself.  This is what people at work here have done and it works ok.

I don't remember the exact details of the metadata as it's been awhile since I've looked into this.